# react native useEffect run into dead loop:

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, setstate

```
export default function CreatePage() {
let [state,setState]=useState({})
let flag=true
useEffect(()=>{
    if(flag){
        axios.get('http://192.168.43.151:3001/data').then((res)=>
    {
        console.log(res.data)
        setState({...res.data})
        flag=false
        console.log(false)
      
    }
    ).catch((err)=>{console.log(err)}).finally(()=>{flag=false})

    }

    
})


return (
    <View >
        <Text>hh</Text>
        <Icon name="heart" size={24} color="#4F8EF7" />
        <Text>first page</Text>
        <Text>{state.name}</Text>
        
    </View>
)
```

}

after the code is executed ,the terminal continues showing :

```
    {"age": 25, "name": "connor", "password": "123456"}
 LOG  false
 LOG  {"age": 25, "name": "connor", "password": "123456"}
 LOG  false
 LOG  {"age": 25, "name": "connor", "password": "123456"}
 LOG  false
```

i have confusion about this ,useEffect function should be rendered once .However ,it seems continuing to be redered .

Comment: You cannot use the `flag` variable like that... use `const [flag, setFlag] = useState(true)` and replace `flag =  false` with `setFlag(false)`. When you write a function component at every re-render the function is called which will create a new variable `flag`. Also, if you want an effect to happen only once you should pass `[]` as second argument to `useEffect`, otherwise the effect is executed at every re-render. As to why the components rerenders I'm not sure, we need a complete example to debug that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not add a dependency array to the useEffect function. Therefore, it is bound to be an infinite reRendering.

And react does not recommend `let`. Use the status value.

You can add a dependency array

```js
const [state,setState] = useState({});
const [flag,setFlag] = useState(true);
useEffect(()=>{
    if(flag){
        axios.get('http://192.168.43.151:3001/data').then((res)=>
    {
        console.log(res.data)
        setState({...res.data})
        setFlag(false)
        console.log(false)
      
    }
    ).catch((err)=>{console.log(err)}).finally(()=>{flag=false})

    }

    
},[])


if(flag) {
   return <LoadingElem />
}

...
```

Comment: ok ,i am  a newer for stackoverflow! and i thank for your pointing out .i dont have enough reputation to upvote,but i have aldready click the checkmark.sorry for late reply!

Comment: @connerbrain  Oh! Thanks no problem~

Answer (score 0):

to execute useEffect only once you have to add dependency array with no dependency. Something like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    // this code will execute only once after first render.
   // some code...
}, [])
```

Comment: thank you ,i ignore the dependency  list of useEffect

Answer (score 0):

> If you want to run an effect and clean it up only once (on mount and unmount), you can pass an empty array ([]) as a second argument to the `useEffect`.

```js
useEffect(() => {}, [])
```